# How do I create a new txt file every time I click on this button?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

```
Private Sub cmdsummary_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdsummary.Click
    Dim writer As New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\Users\salman\Desktop\Text.txt")
    writer.WriteLine(Me.customer.Text + Me.txtcustomer.Text)
    writer.WriteLine(Me.todaystotal.Text + Me.txtsummarytotal.Text)
    writer.WriteLine(Me.average.Text + Me.txtaveragetotal.Text)
    writer.Close()

End Sub
```

Every time I click on cmdsummary it edits the notepad file (txt) and updates it but I want to create a new txt file everytime I click on this button.

Comment: well, what name do you want to give them? You can't have two files with the same name on the same directory, my suggestion depending on what that is is to use the current time 'Now' after 'Text', so, that way it should be different everytime, as long as you wait a second between clicks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'd have to change the name of the textfile or filepath each time, or else it will just keep writing to the same place (and same file).

EDIT: Code with simple counter

```
Dim filesWritten as Integer = 0

Private Sub cmdsummary_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdsummary.Click
    Dim writer As New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\Users\salman\Desktop\Text" & filesWritten & ".txt")
    writer.WriteLine(Me.customer.Text + Me.txtcustomer.Text)
    writer.WriteLine(Me.todaystotal.Text + Me.txtsummarytotal.Text)
    writer.WriteLine(Me.average.Text + Me.txtaveragetotal.Text)
    writer.Close()
    filesWritten+=1
End Sub
```